# T-SQL Skip cte Table and Union when Variable Is Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, common-table-expression

I've got a query that captures all shipments and costs from our factory. Sample data and desired output on Google Drive here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1VndEaGgxNDVpU2M

The issue is we've got 2 different ways of selling things.  One is 'Regluar' where we make it and the other one is a 'buy/sell' where we buy and sell it.

To capture the costs I've had to write two queries, one for each scenario.  The end users of this query can enter in a date range and the query works well then, but I'm stuck when it comes to the variable @Job_No.

All work that goes through our factory (cteRegularJobs) has a Job Number associated with it and I've declared a variable so users can use it to search.  The cteBuyandSell has a value of 'NULL' for Job_No declared in the SELECT statement so I can do a UNION of these two tables at the end.  However, no buy/sell jobs have Job Numbers assigned to them, they are always NULL.

Initially @Job_No is declared as '' and when it's left '' I want the results from both cte tables returned. If there is an entry by the user, i.e. '001' then I want results for cteRegularJobs.

If it makes it easier I am open to declaring the cteBuyandSell.Job_No something else besides NULL, like "Buy and Sell".

The real query is complicated so here's a simplified example of the structure:

```
DELCARE @Job_No AS varchar(10) = '';
SET @Job_No = {User Input or leave as ''};

WITH
    cteBuyandSell AS ( NULL AS 'Job_No',
      ...),
    cteRegularJobs AS (tblJobs.Job_No AS 'Job_No',
      ...
        WHERE tblJobs.Job_No LIKE @Job_No)

SELECT *
FROM
(cteBuyandSell
 UNION
 cteRegularJobs)
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are doing.  Based on your description, the CTE should never return any rows, becuase `tblJobs.Job_No` is NULL in that table -- and `LIKE` never returns true if one operand is `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thank you for the suggestion.  Updated question with link to sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can logically break this up with an IF statement to check the value of your variable. I'd suggest NULL over white space though. Here's an example procedure... with the limited code you provided.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData(@Job_No varchar(10) = NULL)
AS

IF @Job_No IS NULL
    BEGIN

        WITH
            cteBuyandSell AS ( NULL AS 'Job_No',
              ...),
            cteRegularJobs AS (tblJobs.Job_No AS 'Job_No',
              ...
                WHERE tblJobs.Job_No LIKE @Job_No)

        SELECT *
        FROM
        (cteBuyandSell
         UNION
         cteRegularJobs)
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
        WITH
            cteRegularJobs AS (tblJobs.Job_No AS 'Job_No',
              ...
                WHERE tblJobs.Job_No LIKE @Job_No)

        SELECT * FROM cteRetularJobs

    END
```